# populate label with selected gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

l am trying to populate labels with the data of the selected row but lm not winning. I have tried more than 5+ solutions l looked up but none of them are working.

Below is my code:

```
lblBookID.Text = grdLWAPBook.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString();
        lblStudNum.Text = grdLWAPBook.SelectedRow.Cells[1].ToString();
        lblLWAp.Text = grdLWAPBook.SelectedRow.Cells[2].ToString();
        lblDate.Text = grdLWAPBook.SelectedRow.Cells[3].ToString();
        lblTime.Text = grdLWAPBook.SelectedRow.Cells[4].ToString();enter code here
```

Comment: What behavior you get with this code? Any error?

Comment: What event are you subscribing to? Try debugging and using Debug.WriteLine() to dump out the values of the cells as you click on the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your're trying it inside button click event:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;

lblBookID.Text = row.Cells[0].ToString();
```

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell....This what the labels are now populated with. I altered your code to LinkButton because its a link button in ASP.NET